# Text Document, spreadsheet, Presentation editors in Django Python

Tags: javascript, python, django

I've been trying to research for awhile now and I am not getting anywhere so I decided to ask here.
My project is made in Django and I want to add Text Document, spreadsheet, Presentation editors to it (like google docs). I am not sure how to approach this problem. I am willing to even create these from scratch. But I am not sure where to start. Any book, links, API that I can begin with?

I want something that lets people create and edit these documents on my website itself.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It is not an easy task to write it your self :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This all is different applications. For text editors I would recomend look [here](http://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/wysiwyg/)

Other good list of editors is in this [link](http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2008/12/20-excellent-free-rich-text-editors/) 
Some of them support both the text and spreadsheets. Most applications from this link are already connected to django, other you will need to connect by your self.

Comment: Thats for this links. I will look into them tonight :) its just that I wanted to lean on how this technology is created. And I couldn't find any books or material over it